# Solution of advanced functional differential equation

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, recurrence-relations, functional-equations, fractals

**Statement**

Consider an advanced functional differential equation 
$$
Lf(x) = f(2x+\pi)+f(2x-\pi),\quad 
L\equiv\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+1. \tag{1}
$$
Let's construct a solution of Eq. $(1)$ with finite support 
$I\equiv\operatorname{supp}f=\bigl[-\pi,\,\pi\bigr].$

*Notation:*
Denote solution as $\lambda(x),$ i.e. $\lambda(x)\equiv f(x).$

**Solution**

Applying Fourier transform to $(1)$ after some algebra an expression of a spectrum can be obtained
$$
\hat{\lambda}(t)=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot t\cdot 2^{-k}\bigr)}{1-(t\cdot 2^{-k})^2}. \tag{2}
$$
Expression $(2)$ transforms into a simpler one as well
$$
\hat{\lambda}(t) = \operatorname{sinc}(\pi\cdot t)\cdot\prod\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-(t\cdot 2^{-k})^2}. \tag{3}
$$
Solution of $(1)$ is defined by inverse Fourier transform 
$$
\lambda(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx}\cdot\hat{\lambda}(t)\,dt. \tag{4}
$$

**Computation**

Consider an approximation of $\lambda(x)$ by lacunary Fourier series
$$
\lambda(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{2^k}\cos(2^kx).
\tag{5}
$$
Note, that 
$$
a_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_{I}\lambda(x)\cos(nx)\,dx = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\hat{\lambda}(n).
\tag{6}
$$
Function $\hat{\lambda}(t)$ does not vanish only at points $n=2^k,\,k=0,1,\ldots,$ and
$$
a_{2^k} = \dfrac{1}{\pi}\lim_{t\rightarrow 2^k}\hat{\lambda}(t).
\tag{7}
$$
Values of first several coefficients are as follows
$$
\mathbf{a}=(a_0,\,a_1,\,a_2,\,a_4,\,a_8)=\biggl(\frac1\pi,\,2.3\cdot10^{-1},\,7.7\cdot10^{-2},\,-5.1\cdot10^{-3},\, 8.1\cdot10^{-5},\,-3.2\cdot10^{-7}\biggr)
$$

Plot of $\lambda(x)$ graph by $(5)$ with $5$ terms approximation $\mathbf{a}$ is a blue line, first derivative $\lambda'(x)$ (orange), and second derivative $\lambda''(x)$ (green) are shown in the figure
[image: la2 plot]

**Questions**

1. Does a [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) function $\chi_{I}(x)$, which is also a characteristic function of the interval $I$ satisfy the Eq. $(1)?$
2. How to construct a *fast convergence* algorithm to compute values of $f(x)$, like a proposed [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242326/548587)?
3. Derivation an exact expression of $a_{2^k}$ in (7)?

**Discussion**

The problem above is related to the problem of
[Recursive Integration over Piecewise Polynomials: Closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240687/recursive-integration-over-piecewise-polynomials-closed-form/1067358#1067358) and the form of Eq. (1) close to the [Fabius equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261649/a-conjecture-about-certain-values-of-the-fabius-function).

**Reference**

Kolodyazhny, V.M., Rvachov, V.A. Cybern Syst Anal (2007) 43: 893 (page 898). 
DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/s10559-007-0114-y

Comment: Small, pedantic FYI:  the TeX command `\operatorname` can be used to properly format operators like $\operatorname{supp}$ and $\operatorname{sinc}$.  In particular, it will put the right amount of space after the operator, which improves readability (and works much better than `\mathrm`).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you for the notice.

Comment: @reuns I'm not getting why there is no multiplier 2 in terms $e^{\pm i\pi\omega}?$

Comment: Ah I missed that sorry. Then it is not a convolution equation, with the Fourier transform you get $F(\omega) = F(\omega/2) \frac{\cos(\pi  \omega/2)}{1-\omega^2}$ which has solutions in the sense of tempered distributions, bounded on $[-1/2,1/2]$ and away from simple poles at $\pm 2^k \omega$ (those needing a principal value in the inverse Fourier transform)

Comment: @reuns Completely agree, that is how I obtained (2) indeed. It seems to be a standard way.

Comment: $F$ is fully determined by its value on $[-2/3,-1/3] \cup [1/3,2/3]$ and the extension to a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ by $F(\omega) = F(\omega/2) \frac{\cos(\pi  \omega/2)}{1-\omega^2}$ is well-defined whenever $\frac{F(x)-F(1/2)}{x-1/2}$ is $L^1$ around $1/2$

Comment: @reuns Added question 3, any ideas? Seems it's possible to achieve an exact representation of Fourier coefficient.