# On the solution to $u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$ and the Fabius function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, functional-equations, smooth-functions, delay-differential-equations

Looking for closed-form examples of [Delay Differential Equations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) I found that
$$u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$$
could had as solution a modification of the [Fabius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) $F(x)$, which "is an example of an infinitely differentiable function that is nowhere analytic", so is not really a closed-form, but at least is a function which could be explored graphically as is shown [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285939/82135).

But I also found some "incongruences" among different sources as what it is shown [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/243779/909869) and on [this paper](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1702.06487), so I want to know if the following statements are true:

1. From what I think I have understood through other questions, I think that $u(x)=F(x+1)$ fulfills $u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$ for $|x|<1$, Is this true?
2. Under the assumption point (1) is not mistaken, I believe that for extending the result to the whole real line, by itself the Fabius function $F(x)$ is not an alternative since it change values from over and below zero following an intrincated pattern (the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)), but since $u(x)$ allready work in the interval $[-1,\ 1]$ my intuition tells that $z(x)=|F(x+1)|$ should fulfill $z'(x)=2z(2x+1)-2z(2x-1)$ in the whole real line, Is this true?
3. Now under the assumption point (2) is true, my intuition tell that the relation should not be dependent of some location parameter, so for any real-valued constant $a$ the function $q(x)=z(x-a)$ also should fulfill $q'(x)=2q(2x+1)-2q(2x-1)$ in the whole real line, Is this true?

I tried to evaluate them but got confused with the aritmetic (is not that easy, there are a full papers related to it - as the allready mentioned one).

---

*Added later*

So far using an approximation function that don't fulfill the differential equation, but has a similar behavior $$f(t)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$ I am trying on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dx9mcvbjbu) to extend the definition of point (1) which looks true, to fulfill the relation in the whole real line, but so far it looks like the hypothesis (2) and (3) are mistaken.

**It is possible to extend definition (1) to the whole real line? How?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found recently the following [website](https://oeis.org/A288163) that the Rvachëv function mentioned in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06487.pdf) that fulfills in the $\mathbb{R}$ the relation: $$u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$$ its indeed: $$u(x)=\begin{cases} F(x+1),\quad |x|<1\\0,\quad |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ with $F(x)$ the [Fabius function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function)... both the paper and the website signed by Juan Arias de Reyna, so I don't know why its definition is overcomplicated in the paper.

With this the hypothesis of point (2) and (3) are false, but it is interesting how they fail: if I create a train of everly spaced versions of $u(x)$ (using and approximation), the Right-Hand-Side of the DDE makes lobes that matches those of the Left-Hand-Side but also extra lobes were the function is separated by null values, and everything looks both sides are going to fit each others as the lobes in the train becomes near each other, but instead just in the point the lobes becomes joined instead of matching the DDE, the Right-Hand-Side kind of becomes the zero function (the are remaining lobes at the extremes of the finite train I use as approximated example). I don't really get what have happened, but is interesting to see it [here in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5kr20ebdmv).

Answer (score 1):

The link [Recursive Integration over Piecewise Polynomials: Closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240687/recursive-integration-over-piecewise-polynomials-closed-form/243779#243779)
says:

$u(x)$ is a solution if it satisfies below equation,

For $-1 \leq x \leq 0$,
$$u'(x) = 2u(2x+1)$$

For $0 \leq x \leq 1$,
$$u'(x) = -2u(2x-1)$$

The paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06487.pdf says you can satisfy the above with the following definition:

For $-1 \leq x \leq 0$,
$$u(x) = F(x+1)$$

For $0 \leq x \leq 1$,
$$u(x) = F(1-x)$$

Where $F$ is the Fabius function satisfying $F'(x) = 2 F(x)$ as per definition given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function.

So all the answers are consistent.

Regarding extending it to full real line, Not sure.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. What I don't understand is that in the mentioned paper its defined: $$up(x)=\begin{cases} F(x+1),\quad -1\leq x \leq 0 \\ F(1-x),\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0, \quad |x|>1\end{cases}$$ and this function fulfills $$up'(x)=2up(2x+1)-2up(2x-1)$$. But instead in the mentioned question, it is said that the function that fulfills this DDE is $$\frac{F'\left(\frac{x}{2}+1\right)}{2}$$ which look different at least at first sight to the definition of the paper, and both also look different from $$u(x)=F(x+1)$$ which I believe fulfills the DDE. Here is were I am lost.

Comment: Moreover, I have found a few minutes ago [this website](https://oeis.org/A288163) were the function $up(x)$ is defined as I am guessing:$$up(x)=\begin{cases}F(x+1),\quad |x|< 1\\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$... so I think my confussion is somehow justified: the same thing is being defined in several ways that don't look obviously equivalent.

Comment: If you look at the definition of $F$ in these sites, it will be piece wise defined for $x \in [0,1]$ and $ x \in [1,2]$. Match the functions  specific to a piece with corresponding piece in $up(x)$ as defined in paper and you should get the underlying pattern.

Comment: But then why is defined $up(x)$ in a 3 steps piecewise version when is just $F(x+1)$? Experience tells me there is something nontrivial that I am missing.

Comment: Sure. From the looks of it, it seems sometimes they absorb the piece wise definition into definition of $F(x)$. Sometimes they separate it out and put in definition of $up(x)$.